# How to debug a WP 8 app that gets killed by the phone seemingly without any error in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

A bit of a general question perhaps. I have an app that is quite simple, basically a wrapper app for a webpage. This app crashes on WP8, and it happens usually when you start the app, then go to the home screen and hold the back button to bring up the recent apps view and go back into the app. The app is just killed.

What I am wondering is that before when I have had problems with a WP app crashing on WP7.5 I would run the app on the phone from Visual Studio Express and when the app crashed I could see the error and stack trace in VSE. But with the error I am having now its as if VSE doesnt even know that the app has been terminated. It still shows that it is running.

One thing I tried was to add event handlers for the onNavigatedTo event and set a breakpoint in there to see if I could catch the app when I was switching back to it and then do step by step from there. But when I did that and the app crashed all I got from VSE was a message saying that it had failed to bind the breakpoint.

I also tried the emulator, hoping it would give me better insight but its the same as running the app on a phone. So now I have an app that is very unstable on WP8 (works solid as a rock on WP7.5 though) and I have no idea what exactly is going wrong.

So my question is if there is any way to get more information on how and why the app is crashing :)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio exactly?

Comment: Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone that comes with the Windows Phone 8 SDK

Comment: This turned out to be caused by an Access Violation error caused by the embedded IE browser in the app dying if a page loaded in it had the following line of CSS active: box-shadow: 65px 0 30px -30px white inset, -65px 0 30px -30px white inset;

Comment: But the question was not what caused the Access Violation error but rather how to get more information when I had nothing to go on. The answer gave me some new leads to follow.

Comment: So update the question to match the actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to put debug output (`Debug.WriteLine`) in `App_Activated` and `App_Closing methods` in the App.xaml.cs file. And also to the `RootFrame_NavigationFailed` and `Application_UnhandledException`. All those methods has a potential to run when you return to your app and it crashes. If this would not help (you'll see no output in VS Output window), try putting some other output there, like writing synchronously to a file in the isolated storage, or activate some launcher (like email compose task, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)). The point here is to perform some other activity when failure happens.

Another thing you could try is to break execution in VSE, when app is already seems to be terminated. I mean, pressing the "pause" button in the debugger. It could potentially be informative.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use the Event View of Windows.

I have a similiar problem (sometimes while running and accessing the isolated storage the app just gets killed without any notice) and the event views provides some useful information.